# How to filter column based on range of values from another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like below, where y is the target (either 0 or 1). How do I find what percentage of y is either 0 or 1, based on a range of values of my x?

Example: For values of x between 0 and 20, the corresponding y is 10% 1 (and 90% 0).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1st we can use `pd.cut` , then `crosstab`

```
out = pd.crosstab(pd.cut(df['x'], [0,20,....]),df['y'], normalize='index')
```

Comment: hey, I used this and it works, thanks! any chance you know how to easily put the 'out' df into a bar chart? (x would be the bins, and y would be the percentage of 1, for example).

Answer (score 1):

I hope you like one-liners. Assuming `a` is your dataframe:

```
a.loc[(a.x < 20) & (a.x > 0),'y'].value_counts(normalize=True).to_frame('frequency')
```